# System.RankException Error in Visual Basic When Passing Array to Function

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm having some serious difficulty with this.  Anyone thing they can help me out?

Variable Declaration (Outside of any sub)

```
Dim notes = New String() {"A", "A#/Bb", "B", "C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab"}

Dim boxString1 = New TextBox()  {boxSt1Pos1, boxSt1Pos2, boxSt1Pos3, boxSt1Pos4, boxSt1Pos5, boxSt1Pos6, boxSt1Pos7,
    boxSt1Pos8, boxSt1Pos9, boxSt1Pos10, boxSt1Pos11, boxSt1Pos12, boxSt1Pos13, boxSt1Pos14,
    boxSt1Pos15, boxSt1Pos16, boxSt1Pos17, boxSt1Pos18, boxSt1Pos19, boxSt1Pos20, boxSt1Pos21,
    boxSt1Pos22, boxSt1Pos23, boxSt1Pos2, boxSt1Pos25}
```

Function Signature (Outside of any sub)

```
Function populateStrings(startPos As Integer, ByRef gString As TextBox(), ByVal notes As String())
```

Function Call (Inside form.load sub)

```
Call populateStrings(3, boxString1(), notes())
```

The program builds fine but errors when run, stating the aforementioned error, and I can't manually define dimensions anywhere in the function signature or call.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read the help for formatting code in your posts - you're currently writing them as if you were quoting something.

Comment: Do you have Option Strict on? I'd *expect* you to call it as `populateStrings(3, boxString1, notes)`

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting.

Comment: I changed the "Option Explicit" to "Strict," didn't change anything though.  I don't think the problem is with data type conversions, RankException has something to do with the incorrect number of dimensions being passed, but I don't see where I'm doing that wrong.   Also gave your suggestion a shot, but it caused a Null Pointer Reference exception with the passed arrays.